# I cannot create the database GradeBook with the foreign key. When I try to add it I get error1046: choose database

Tags: mysql

CREATE SCHEMA GRADEBOOK;

CREATE TABLE GRADEBOOK.PERSON
(PERSON_ID      INT                                 NOT NULL,
Fname           varchar(15)                         NOT NULL,
Minit           varchar (1),
Lname           varchar(15)                         NOT NULL,
B_date          date                                NOT NULL,
SEX             varchar(1)                          NOT NULL,
ADDRESS         varchar(50)                         NOT NULL,
TELEPHONE       VARCHAR(12),
STATUS          varchar(10)                         NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (PERSON_ID))
 ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE GRADEBOOK.STUDENT
(STUDENT_ID     INT                                 NOT NULL,
SUBJECT_ID      VARCHAR (30)                        NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (STUDENT_ID))
 ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE GRADEBOOK.ALUMNUS
(STUDENT_ID     INT                                 NOT NULL,
GRAD_YEAR       date                                NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(STUDENT_ID))
 ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE GRADEBOOK.SUBJECT
(SUBJECT_ID     VARCHAR (30)                        NOT NULL,
SUBJECT_NAME    VARCHAR (20)                        NOT NULL,
CLASS_ID        VARCHAR (20)                        NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (SUBJECT_ID))
 ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE GRADEBOOK.HOUSE
(HOUSE_ID       INT                                 NOT NULL,
HOUSE_NAME      VARCHAR (20)                        NOT NULL,
HOUSE_COLOR     VARCHAR (20)                        NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (HOUSE_ID))
 ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE GRADEBOOK.CLUB
(CLUB_ID        INT auto_increment                  NOT NULL,
CLUB_name       varchar(20)                         NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CLUB_ID))
 ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE GRADEBOOK.HOMEROOM
(HOMEROOM_ID    VARCHAR(20)                         NOT NULL,
CLASS_ID        VARCHAR(20)                         NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY( HOMEROOM_ID))
 ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE GRADEBOOK.CLASS
(CLASS_ID       VARCHAR(20)                         NOT NULL,
CLASS_name      VARCHAR(20)                         NOT NULL,
HOMEROOM_ID     VARCHAR(20)                         NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (CLASS_ID))
 ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE GRADEBOOK.TEACHER
(TEACHER_ID          INT                        NOT NULL,
HOOMROOM             VARCHAR(20)                NOT NULL,
SUBJECT_ID          VARCHAR(20)                 NOT NULL,
YEAR                INT                     NOT NULL,
TERM                VARCHAR(20)                 NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY(TEACHER_ID))
 ENGINE=INNODB;

Comment: Have you chosen the database to apply this query too...?